# Unable to save data in picture library SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, column, picture-library, picture

I have created picture library using default template in SharePoint 2013 site.
I have created new columns for picture library.
[image]

In above image, I trying to save new value for Country column.
when I click on save button. Item get saved. but after that when I open same item in view/edit mode.

I'm not able to find the change that I have made for Country column value.
but the item Last modified date get changed.
Please suggest some solution

**Here is my picture library view**

[image]

Comment: Please check the value from callout menu from the image and select the view property/edit property you will see the updated value of country

Comment: I have already checked. still not updated value.

Comment: can please show your all pictures view because i did the same and it reflected on all picture view of picture library

Comment: Sunil I have undated question. please check Picture library view

Comment: Thanks ,but i meant "All Pictures" view . Please select All pictures next to thumbnails.

Comment: Is Country an MMS column or just a text column?

Comment: Just a text column.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your site collection and create new one and then check with the picture library.
Hope, it should work.

Comment: this operation too costly.. 
I don't want to delete site collection..

Comment: still I don't think that's the final option..!